# How to make wget download all mp3 files from a website and bypass an annoying ad each time?

Tags: linux, download, wget, mp3

I want to download all mp3 files hosted on this [website](http://www.dailytehillim.com/Default.aspx), as you can see the website fires up an ad page referring the visitor to their new website. The new website is a larger one and it would be easier, in my opinion, to get the desired mp3 from the older one.

My trial was like that:

```
wget -r -A mp3 http://www.dailytehillim.com/
```

It didn't work. I need to download all the 150 mp3 files as shown below in one command line rather than clicking all of them, removing the annoying ad each time and making the download.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the permission or appropriate license to download the contents of that website, you can use the below code. However, if you don't have any of those, I suggest you to not to use this code because you might be infringing the copyright laws and it's illegal as far as I know.

MP3 Format

```
for i in {1..150}
do
    wget "http://www.dailytehillim.com/Save.aspx?t=m&ID="$i
done
```

WMA Format

```
for i in {1..150}
do
    wget "http://www.dailytehillim.com/Save.aspx?t=w&ID="$i
done
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How could you figure out the link to be `../Save.aspx?t=m&ID=` in that particular website, what was your clue to that? and can one choose the wma format instead of the mp3 using your command line?